# How to Install the CUDA Driver for TensorFlow (installing from source)

Tags: cuda, driver, tensorflow, ubuntu-15.04

I'm trying to [build TensorFlow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources) and run it with GPU support. To install the toolkit I use the runfile, to install the driver I used the Additional Drivers Tool, since I did not get Ubuntu to boot into Text mode as specified in the [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-installation) and `stop lightdm` and `start lightdm` does not work either, it gives me (also with sudo):

```
Name com.ubuntu.Upstart does not exist
```

So far I could build a release from the TensorFlow repository. However, when I'm trying to run the example as specified in the how-to

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu
```

the GPU apparently cannot be found:

```
jonas@jonas-Aspire-V5-591G:~/Documents/repos/tensoflow_fork$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:491] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:153] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: jonas-Aspire-V5-591G
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:160] hostname: jonas-Aspire-V5-591G
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:185] libcuda reported version is: 352.63.0
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:356] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 21:25:42 PST 2015 GCC version:  gcc version
    4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)  """
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] kernel reported version is: 352.63.0
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:293] kernel version seems to match DSO: 352.63.0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:81] No GPU devices available on machine.
F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:125] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0", "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot assign a device to node 'y': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
     [[Node: y = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/gpu:0"](Const, x)]])
Aborted
```

I'm using a clean Ubuntu 15.04 installation on an Acer Notebook with the GTX950M.

Can anybody tell me how to properly install the driver?

Comment: refer to [failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120389/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

Can you run `deviceQuery` (comes with cuda installation)? Can you see nvidia present in lspci/lsmod/nvidia-smi?

```
lsmod |grep nvidia 
dmesg | grep -i nvidia
lspci | grep -i nvidia
nvidia-smi
```

You can reload nvidia module and look for error messages

```
modprobe -r nvidia
dmesg | tail
sudo dmesg | grep NVRM
```

Related issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/601

Comment: Thanks, but I finally got it running on Ubuntu 16.04 by adding the [graphics-drivers repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html) and installing the latest stable version via the additional drivers...